# How to display all the images in a folder by using django

Tags: python, django

I have a folder which is being populated by images all the time . And I don't know how to make a kind of "loop" which will display all the images in a browser using Django

Comment: To get a kind of loop, you'll have to write some kind of code.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely should have provided some code, but anyway here’s a quick way I think should solve your problem.
I am guessing the image folder is tucked away somewhere in the media folder and already linked in the settings.py file. So simply do these in the views.py and the Django template and you should be good.

Views.py

```
def gallery_view(request):
    path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT
    img_list = os.listdir(path + "(path to image folder in media)")
    context = {"images": img_list}
    return render (request, '(path to django template)', context)
```

Template

```
{% for image in images %}
<img  src="{{MEDIA_URL}}path to image folder{{image}}">
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

it depends on what the usage. you can use file methods like `open()` and read the image data, taking a relative path of the folder with respect to your `BASE_DIR`. Or if the images are static file, you just need to add a `STATIC_URL` and get them from your template using template tags.

However, you should give us some code, it will help us know your problem